# Como fazer um script Python executar um Click no Windows 10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, click, eventos-do-mouse

Estou tentando um script simples com python, ele clicar em uma coordenada da tela.

Já tentei com Pyautogui, pynput, pydirectinput, pywinauto... Mas em nenhuma delas o click é realmente efetuado, a única coisa que funciona é mover o mouse até a coordenada.

os scripts são simples, mas mesmo assim não funciona, por dedução acho que seja um problema relacionado ao win10.

Alguém sabe como posso resolver isso?

Preciso instalar algo a mais, talvez um driver?

Tá faltando dar algum tipo de permissão?

tem alguma forma de eu dar comando pro hardware do mouse efetuar o click, ao invés de ser um click virtualizado?

Estou perdido :(

**Algumas de minhas tentativas abaixo**

**OBS:** Em todas tentativas o mouse se move, mas não clica.

> Pyautogui:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.moveTo(35, 240)
pyautogui.click()
```

> Pydirectinput:

```
import pyautogui
import pydirectinput
pydirectinput.moveTo(35, 240)
pydirectinput.click()
```

> pywinauto:

```
import pywinauto
from pywinauto import Desktop, Application, mouse, findwindows

pywinauto.mouse.move(coords=(160, 400))
pywinauto.mouse.double_click(button='left', coords=(160, 400))
```

> Direct windows click:

```
import win32api, win32con
def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)
click(10,200)
```

> Autoclicker usando pynput:

```
import time
import threading
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode


delay = 0.001
button = Button.left
start_stop_key = KeyCode(char='s')
exit_key = KeyCode(char='e')


class ClickMouse(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, delay, button):
        super(ClickMouse, self).__init__()
        self.delay = delay
        self.button = button
        self.running = False
        self.program_running = True

    def start_clicking(self):
        self.running = True

    def stop_clicking(self):
        self.running = False

    def exit(self):
        self.stop_clicking()
        self.program_running = False

    def run(self):
        while self.program_running:
            while self.running:
                mouse.click(self.button)
                time.sleep(self.delay)
            time.sleep(0.1)


mouse = Controller()
click_thread = ClickMouse(delay, button)
click_thread.start()


def on_press(key):
    if key == start_stop_key:
        if click_thread.running:
            click_thread.stop_clicking()
        else:
            click_thread.start_clicking()
    elif key == exit_key:
        click_thread.exit()
        listener.stop()


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Você tentou `pyautogui.click(x=35, y=240)`?

Comment: sim, ele se move mais não clica

Comment: se o o usuario tiver permissão administrativa tranquilo, ja a api ela levanta um alerta exception indicando que precisa de autorização, mas parece que a api já tratou essa questão de acordo com essa pergunta feita "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38486151/pyautogui-click-permissions-error" . A lib pyautogui possibilita escolher qual botão do mouse sera usado tbm.

Comment: Neste caso, use do jeito que você fez, mas coloque um `time.sleep(1)` entre mover e clicar

Comment: Estou rodando em powershell como administrador, e mesmo assim não funciona: 
https://i.imgur.com/FwhfcSF.gif

Paulo Marques, não funciona nem com time. ja tentei